# Error Jquery.$.get() request

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i access this url: http://jservice.io/api/random the output is something like this:

```
[{
    "id": 67917,
    "answer": "agua",
    "question": "After some fierce flamencoing, you might hear cries of this, Spanish for \"water\"",
    "value": 800,
    "airdate": "2004-11-18T12:00:00.000Z",
    "created_at": "2014-02-11T23:29:50.743Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-02-11T23:29:50.743Z",
    "category_id": 1145,
    "game_id": null,
    "invalid_count": null,
    "category": {
        "id": 1145,
        "title": "foreign words \u0026 phrases",
        "created_at": "2014-02-11T22:52:16.443Z",
        "updated_at": "2014-02-11T22:52:16.443Z",
        "clues_count": 115
    }
}]
```

I'm trying to use `$.get()` to get the data of request:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script>
    $.get("http://jservice.io/api/random", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data.title + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

But the output is this:

```
Data: undefined
Status: success
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `data.title`.

1. `data` is an array.
2. `title` is nested under the array element's `category`.

For this *specific* response, you'd need (roughly):

```
data[0].category.title
```

But if you can get multiple results back, you need to decide what you're actually going to do.

Answer (score 3):

The return was an array. So you have to use
`data[0]`. Also the `title` is inside the `category` object.
Try this.

```js
    $.get("http://jservice.io/api/random", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data[0].category.title + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The result can also be achieved by accessing the url as json object. Sharing below code for reference.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
(function() {
  var srcURL = "http://jservice.io/api/random";
  $.getJSON( srcURL, {    
    format: "json"
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
    $.each( data, function( i, item ) {             
      console.log(item.category.title);
    });
  });
})();
</script>
</html>
```